# How does one detect linguistic recursion so as to know how much nesting there is, if any?

Tags: natural-language-processing, computational-linguistics

To be clear, [recursion in linguistics is here better called "nesting"](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3254/28348) in this CS context to avoid confusing it with the *other* recursion. How does one detect nesting? I am particularly interested in the example case of conjunctions. For example: say that I want to look for sentences that look like this:

> Would you rather have ten goldfish **or** a raccoon?

Seems straightforward: a binary choice. However, how do you distinguish a binary choice with nesting from a ternary (or *n*-ary) choice?

> Would you rather have (one **or** two dogs) **or** (a raccoon)?
>
> Would you rather have (two dogs) **or** (ten goldfish) **or** (a raccoon)?

Ditto for implied uses of "or," which is more common than the latter of the above:

> Would you rather have (one **or** two dogs),***[nothing]*** (ten goldfish), **or** (a raccoon)?

Given the available tools for NLP (POS-taggers and the like), how do you count the number of conjunctions to say "there are *n* surface-level clauses in the sentence, with *n*-or-zero clauses nested within."?